# Jquery get url return heders for error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create some functionality for accessing my ip camera.

Basically the get function fails even though it should work as the feed works. The feed is a direct link to an image which gets created via a cgi script on the camera.

It works when you go to it directly, I think it fails because of a time out or because of unusual headers returned.

I am trying to determine the headers returned so I can debug and create functions around there, the final aim is to get the video stream to load in the img tags else if there is an issue show a no feed available image.

```
var geturl;
geturl = $.get( "http://camurl/videostream.cgi", function() {
    alert( "success" );
});
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
});
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" + geturl.getAllResponseHeaders());
});
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

I have tried various jquery functions found on here and on the api, but the alert box just fails on an attempt to use them, or nothing is returned as shown below the alert is just error

This is probably something really simple.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like you've got several syntax errors in the code above; is this a direct copy from the script you're using? if not, please clean it up before we attempt to troubleshoot - thanks!

Comment: Really, where are the syntax errors, I have just done a direct copy and paste. the orginal code was taken from jquery api http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ I have not changed any syntax, but added in the geturl and headers

Comment: Looks like your edit got it working - taking a look now. (Originally there were some quotes missing).

Comment: ahh ok, sorry I added in a bit at the last minute to try something else. Failed also tried this function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    var headers = XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders();
} but it failed

Comment: If I try a regular GET with the url provided, it does not return a response from the server. It seems that videostream.cgi isn't working? Can you double check the URL?

Comment: There are still syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Before `.done`, `.fail` and `.always` is the `;` to much. It should be: `$.get("..").done(function(){...}).fail(function(){...});`

Comment: Are you familiar with Fiddler? I find it to be an indispensable tool for HTTP hacking. You can use to to compare the HTTP requests/responses you get using the two methods (i.e. 'regular' vs jQuery). Perhaps that will set you on the right track. You can download it from [fiddler2.com](http://fiddler2.com/).

Comment: thats not the actual url for security reason I did not post it. and the ; should not matter where it is. the syntax errors are not the issuse, the issues is returning the headers to see why jquery thinks it has failed. it maybe because its just returning an image with no http headers, but unless I can display the headers I cant see what the issue is

Comment: @EiríkurFannarTorfason fiddler won't do any good in this case because the videostream.cgi isn't receiving a response from the server ;)

Answer (score 0):

`videostream.cgi` is not working - this may be due to the encoding of the source video?

Try this url instead: `http://camurl/snapshot.cgi?user=test&pwd=******&resolution=32&rate=0`

Here is a working example of proper $.ajax syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/WfVrh/

Note that snapshot.cgi is producing a jpeg instead here.

I found this on their documentation here: http://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=TENVIS

Further on the topic of videostream.cgi - this is the result of a GET:

[image]

Edit: I'm assuming you've disabled the user/pass that we were testing with, but please see if this works.

Comment: Added a jsfiddle ^ take a look; your $.get syntax is still incorrect.

Comment: still not showing the error, it displays when I change console to alert, but nothing shows after the word error its just blank..

Comment: Yes, I changed IP and details, I didn't mean to post the actual link to it

Comment: ahaa If I changed textStatus to Errorthrown, it actually gives me the error. which is malformed html, but on my machine I get blank.. Let me do some more debugging quick as its now working on jsfiddle. Thanks for your help so far, Ill get back to you shortly

Comment: Ok so I have made some progess with     $.ajax({
    url: "http://xxxxxx",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown){alert(xhr.status+" - statsu = " + statusText + " - error =" + errorThrown)}

}); but still getting a 404 or it just loads and never stops

Comment: Yeah - that's what I was saying that the videostream.cgi is broken (or it's serving a live feed handler). Try snapshot.cgi to see if it works?

Comment: it still doesnt work, the headers show fine with stuff like curl on php, its something funky on jquery. the page exists. it would be good to add custom error handler

Comment: Try playing around in the fiddle I added http://jsfiddle.net/remus/WfVrh/ -- change the values in the .js and click Run, see if it logs anything to the console.